# IPv6 (anycast/unicast/multicast) и IPv4

Tags: сеть, ipv6, mask

1. Можно ли присвоить сетевому адаптеру только multicast адрес?
2. Можно ли присвоить сетевому адаптеру только anycast адрес?
3. Можно ли присвоить сетевому адаптеру только unicast адрес?
   **Доп. вопрос:** Какому узлу будет доставлен пакет с адресом 63.255.255.255 и маской 192.0.0.0? (как правильно высчитать).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Можно. Отсутствие Unicast IP не является препятствием для участия адаптера в Multicast-группах.
2. Нельзя, поскольку Anycast адресов не существует, технология реализуется на уровне маршрутизации.
3. Можно.
4. Broadcast на подсеть. Если исключить наличие подвоха в вопросе, то пакет будет доставлен всем узлам сети 63.0.0.0/2.